# Assign different record types to different users of the same profile

Tags: record-type

Is there a way to assign different record type of case object to different users having same profile. I have a requirement to show department specific picklist values on case object's when specific department user logs in and try to create new case. All department falls under same profile I am not thinking of creating separate profile for each department.

**So the requirement is:** If User U1 of Department D1 having profile R logs in, he should see only R1 record type of case object. But when User U2 or Department D2 or same profile R logs in, he should see only R2 record type of case object. It will apply for other department as well.

**What I have done so far:** 1. Created record types and assigned all record type to Profile R. There will be one record type as default because there is no option to disable default option. User in this case getting option to select one record type but values are coming from default record type only.
2. Created permission set for each department and removed all record type from profile level and assigned to specific permission set. Then assigned specific permission set to one user at a time. In this case record type selection option is not appearing but values are from master record type which is default in case of no record type.

**How can I disable default record type since values are coming from default only**

Any suggestion in this case will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are heading in the right direction - permission sets allow changes in permissions for individual users over and above their profile-based permissions. However, Permission Sets are only additive; you cannot use them to take away permissions.

To do what you want to do, remove all permissions for the specified object (Case) from the profile - by this I mean all CRUD permissions, not just record types - and use permission sets **only** to add access to Case with the desired record types and CRUD permissions.

Comment: Thanks Phil, 
But I am only adding record type access from permission set not removing anything. At profile level no record type is set and have done through permission.
What all permissions you want me to remove from profile ? Is that about case object access as well ?

Comment: I mean, you need to remove CRUD access to Case in the profile, and only add that through the permission set.

Comment: Tried this one as well. Removed CRUD access from profile and added into permission set but in this case as well, values from master record type populating.

Comment: Surprising, and makes me think something else is incorrectly configured somewhere...

Comment: As per this page, 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/permissions_record_type_access.htm

if master is set at profile and only one record type at permission set then records from permission set should appear. But record from master is appearing here.

Comment: My point was not to set **anything** at the profile level and to leave it all to the permission sets. Though as that document says, a permission set doesn't allow definition of the default. Hmmm.