# Assigning record type via Permission sets to eliminate user selecting upon record creation whilst different user groups have same Profile

Tags: permission-sets

**Aim:** Have 2 record types with 2 page layouts for 2 groups of users of the same profile for a custom object but ensuring each group are not faced with a record type selection/prompt upon record creation.

**What I have done:** Created my record types + associated page layouts and 2 permission sets - 1 for group A with record type A access only and 1 for group B with record type B access only. The default record type on the Profile is the --Master-- as per this article https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/permissions_record_type_access.htm

**Issue with outcome:** Whilst this works in my sandbox, it is not working in my prod org. Group A sees the correct record type+page layout however Group B sees record type A but with the correct picklist values for some overlapping fields of the 2 page layouts but isn't the page layout I had created for Group B.

**Troubleshooting attempts:** as per other questions ([Assign different record types to different users of the same profile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308643/assign-different-record-types-to-different-users-of-the-same-profile)) I have attempted to remove CRED on the Profile level and managed this through the 2 permission sets but it hasn't solved the issue.

Any help would be very much appreciated